# Power series of the function $e^{ax}cos(bx)$

Tags: analysis, power-series

**Question**

How can I show that the power series of the function $e^{ax}cos(bx),a>0,b>0$ in powers of x has either no zero coefficients or infinitely many zero coefficients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$e^{ax}\cos bx$ is the real part of
$$\exp(ax+ibx)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a+bi)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
I suggest you write $a+bi=re^{it}$ and think about what $(a+bi)^n$
having real part zero means for $n$ and $t$.